# Not all options displayed on form

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I'm working on my webservice (table) and indeed I can edit, add and delete some records with php. 
If I want to add some records I got the button "add blood bank member" and this shows up a formula.

**My problem** 
If I open the formula not all options will be shown. That means that I can see the gender, age but I do not see the first options of the formula like firstname and so on.

**What I did** 
I thought about a CSS problem and saw on the file that the not displayed forms got the following input class:

```
<input class="uk-input">
```

I then changed in CSS the `color` and `background-color` of `uk-input` but it did not help.

Here is the complete form:

```
<h2 class="uk-modal-title">ADD Blood Bank Member</h2>

          <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

         <div class="uk-margin">

            <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="First Name" name="first" required>
        </div>

         <div class="uk-margin">

            <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" name="last" required>
        </div>

         <div class="uk-margin">

            <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" required>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-margin">

            <input class="uk-input" type="text" placeholder="Age" name="age" required>
        </div>



            <div class="uk-margin">
            Gender<select class="uk-select" name="gender" required>
                <option selected>Male</option>
                <option>Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

And here is an image of the formula:

[image]

What's wrong with this formula?

Comment: could you provide a css `.uk-input` declatarion?

Comment: The form markup seems ok. You can use the inspector from the developer tools to see which css rules apply to the elements. Is there any javascript involved that may hide theese items?

Comment: Picture has a "Blood group" field, while the form code doesn't. Is it actual code?

Comment: @Banzay The css file is really large and there are multiple .uk-input fields so I uploaded here: https://files.fm/u/xq9k6p8d

Comment: @Ebby Hi Ebby, unfortunately there isnt any js files included.

Comment: Contrary to my first comment ... the form element is not closed.
Whether it really is a CSS problem, you can easily find out by putting the css out for a short time. If so, you must search the appropriate rule with the inspector.

Comment: Can't duplicate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/uhbanmsf/2/

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Thats quite strange. Now I copy pasted the code (css and html) and cant see everything on my formular = same problem as before.

Comment: @sdada, check and see if you have another css file that over-rides the css file you are referencing to

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen In css there are multiple options, like focus and so one. Which one is for the stanadlone forms?

Comment: @sdada, you should check your html file and see if there are multiple css links. At this point, I think the only solution is to use element inspection with developer tools https://developer.chrome.com/devtools

Comment: @sdada, check the link I provide, and you should be able to click the form and find the elements inside, then click the element inside to see what css rules are applied (right panel) to that element

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Already checked it out with multiple css. So now I did with the inspector and can you explain something to me. How is it possible that if I change the css on the inspector the change will be made but not on the file on my pc?

Comment: @sdada , no, you cannot, but you will be able to find the line number and update your local file according.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen Yes I know but the change wont be made if I do it on my local file. Thats what I mean and yes I changed the right line/s.

Comment: @sdada, if that's an external css. You can create a seperate css file. Example: style.css after the external css to over-rides the value.

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen It did not worked. :(

Comment: Update your question with more information. We can’t help in the dark. Share your html css link as well

Comment: @MichaelEugeneYuen So here you got the css files. I saw on the inspector that I had to change something on main.css on line 2341 for the background but this did not helped. But as you can see on https://files.fm/u/xq9k6p8d, there isnt any linked main.css

Comment: @sdada, if you suspect it's a background issue, try using inline css: <div class="uk-margin" style="background-color: red;">

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use JS to detect if the gender and blood group input is empty or not. First set first name last name and phone display is none, then if the input of gender and blood group is not empty then set the first name last name and phone number's display as inline-block.